# Why didn't Kane suffocate before he got back to the Nostromo?

Tags: alien-franchise

Right after Kane discovered the Xenomorph egg cluster things went downhill. First of all, his suit was ruptured. Next, he was embraced for a long time in an oxygen poor environment before he was dragged and hauled back to a breathable atmosphere. How did Kane breath after the facehugger breached his environmental suit?

Comment: Ehm, didn't it feed him oxygen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28creature_in_Alien_franchise%29#Facehugger) (emphasis mine)

> Upon making contact, the facehugger tightens its tail around the
>   host's neck in order to render it unconscious through oxygen
>   deprivation. The facehugger then inserts a proboscis down the host's
>   throat, **supplying it with oxygen** while simultaneously implanting
>   an embryo

Comment: How does it supply him with oxygen? That it could would imply the Xenomorph understood enviromental suits.

Comment: @MajorStackings As to the how, the only conclusion based on what we see in the films is that the facehugger somehow absorbs oxygen from the air around it, filters it out and passes it into the proboscis/ovipositor. The more relevant question is how did it know to supply him with oxygen instead of, say, nitrogen. And I don't think there's a clear answer to that in the current evidence (but I think you could come up with a working theory based on what's in Prometheus).

Answer (score 1):

The how part is not covered in the film but it is definitively explained by ash when he was talking to Dallas that the face hugger was keeping Kane alive.